# If object size increases, shouldn't magnification decrease by formula

Tags: optics

According to the magnification formula, magnification is the image size by object size
According to this if object comes near and its size increases shouldn't magnification decrease?

Comment: Moving an object does not change its size

Comment: Are you asking about linear magnification or angular magnification?

Comment: @Farcher Linear

Comment: Then note @AaronStevens comment which states that the linear size of an object does not depend on its position relative to an optical system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magnification is an inherent property of the lens, independent of the height and distance of the original object.  Let’s say we are moving a toy car towards the lens, then the distance between object and the lens decreases, but the distance between the image decreases too.  The formula is $M=\frac{d_i}{d_o}$.

On the other hand, if your object is larger, then the image becomes larger (higher).    $M=\frac{H_i}{H_o}$ is the formula for magnification.  Hence, these two factors are independent of the magnification:  the magnification of a lens is constant.

Comment: But linear magnification is not constant for the lens. If we move the object from one location to another then its height does not change, but it's image height will change, hence giving a different magnification. $M$ is not constant.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @QuIKmAtHs is not correct.

The lensmaker's formula: $$1/d_1 + 1/d_2 = 1/f$$ is a good starting point.  The magnification is, indeed, $$ M = d_2/d_1;$$ but $d_2$ does not decrease when $d_1$ decreases; it typically *increases* when $d_1$ decreases.  When $d_1 = f$, the magnification is essentially infinite.

When you see a lens labeled "5x", the 5x refers to angular magnification, not magnification of the size of the image relative to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Magnification of the *focused* object can be shown to be:

$m = \frac{f}{s-f}$,

where $f$ is the focal distance and $s$ distance from the object to the lens. So if you keep your subject in focus as it comes closer, magnification will indeed *increase*, not decrease.

In case you only focus the lens once and then move the object around without changing that focus, there is a bit different formula for a defocused object:

$m_d = \frac{s m}{s_d}$,

where $m$ is the magnification at the focused point, $s$ the distance of that focused spot, and $m_d$ and $s_d$ magnification and distance at the defocused spot. As you can see, the relationship still stays the same: magnification *increases* as the object gets closer.

Comment: Think of it like this: your eyes have a lens each. As an object gets closer, it will look bigger to you, even though its size hasn't changed. Obviously, the magnification increased, so your eye sees a bigger image.